# Read one Value of a specific object from a json file

Tags: json, powershell

I want to return only the hash value of one object from my test.json file.

Right now, I am getting all hash values with my code.

json file:

```
[
{
    "name": "abc.txt",
    "hash": "D23FC7C4C9F1ED7CD147D7D29E3A541D"
},
{
    "name": "def.txt",
    "hash": "681B75B81734F7215C2DAD1F7EDFDAF7"
},
{
    "name": "ghi.txt",
    "hash": "81709CDC04EBDBDAA9BA15F6CAF1F05B"
},
{
    "name": "xyz.txt",
    "hash": "56F07815D06966FA3A73275797496881"
}
]
```

My code:

```
$jsonFile = $PSScriptRoot + "\test.json"
(Get-Content $jsonFile | ConvertFrom-Json | where {$_.name -eq 'abc.txt'}).hash
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Careful with the parentheses:

```
((Get-Content $jsonFile | ConvertFrom-Json) | where {$_.name -eq "abc.txt"}).hash
#D23FC7C4C9F1ED7CD147D7D29E3A541D
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this your json file contains a list of dictionaries. First you need to select which item of your list you want to have and then you can retrieve the value based on the key.

Try something like this:

```
$jsonFile = $PSScriptRoot + "\test.json"
$jsonList = Get-Content $jsonFile | ConvertFrom-Json
$jsonList[0].hash
```

Alternatively:

```
$jsonObject = $jsonList | Where-Object {$_.name -eq 'abc.txt'} | Select-Object hash
```